# Remove rows with conditions

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with repeated IDs, I want to remove duplicates in the ID column, so each person appears only once. But I would like R to remove those following a rule. There is a column for antibodies. These patients could have tested:

- always positive
- always negative
- positive and then negative
- negative and then positive

My interest is to know whether they have ever tested positive. So I would like to keep just one value per ID following this rule:

- if they always tested positive (keep just 1, a random positive value)
- if they always tested negative (keep just 1, a random negative value)
- if they have tested positive and then negative (keep just 1, a random positive value)
- if they have tested negative and then positive (keep just 1, a random positive value)

It is VERY important that selected ID, keeps its original values in the row this is: if for ID3, you pick positive in row 10, then values for AA and BB should be 568 and 45645 respectively. Because it is very important to know what kind of AA or BB values are associated to positive or negative antibody status.

A comment below has suggested to use

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(antibodies = ifelse(any(antibodies == "positive"),
                                "positive",
                                "negative"),
            AA = first(AA),
            BB = first(BB))
```

But this carries the risk of positive values not always being in the first row, and therefore in some cases I could be picking negative AA and BB and associate it to a positive value.

I illustrate my text with the following example:

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 antibodies = c("positive","positive","positive","positive",
                                "negative","negative","negative","negative",
                                "positive","positive","negative","negative"), AA= c(123,345,7567,234,8679,890,812,435345,567,568,786,678), BB= c(3453,456,67867,35,78,234235,978978,234,786,45645,4756,7567),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from the example is easy enough to reproduce,  I think the following example covers it. As a solution I use a `group_by()` from the dplyr package to summarise the data to one record per unique ID. Using an `ifelse()` statement we can check if **any** of the original records were positive - in that case the final value is also positive. If this is not the case, the final value must be negative.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 antibodies = c("positive","positive","positive","positive",
                                "negative","negative","negative","negative",
                                "positive","positive","negative","negative"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(antibodies = ifelse(any(antibodies == "positive"),
                                "positive",
                                "negative"))
```

This gives the output

```
     ID antibodies
  <dbl> <chr>     
1     1 positive  
2     2 negative  
3     3 positive
```

UPDATE AFTER QUESTION WAS EDITED:

The question was changed to include two extra column. To include the first value for every ID for columns AA and BB in the final data frame, you can add these to the `summarise()` statement (we first arrange descending on the antibodies column to ensure the first row is a 'positive' one if there is any):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 antibodies = c("positive","positive","positive","positive",
                                "negative","negative","negative","negative",
                                "negative","positive","positive","negative"),
                 AA = c(123, 345, 7567, 234, 8679, 890, 
                        812, 435345, 567, 568, 786, 678),
                 BB = c(3453, 456, 67867, 35, 78, 234235,
                        978978, 234, 786, 45645, 4756, 7567),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(desc(antibodies)) %>% 
  summarise(antibodies = ifelse(any(antibodies == "positive"),
                                "positive",
                                "negative"),
            AA = first(AA),
            BB = first(BB))
```

this gives the output:

```
     ID antibodies    AA    BB
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 positive     123  3453
2     2 negative    8679    78
3     3 positive     568 45645
```

Comment: Dear @pieterbons, Thank you so much for your easy code! it woks perfectly! However, I would like to keep the extra rows as in the example I don't mind the values that are kept in the other rows, but I need them. 

How could I trick the code? - THanks!!

Comment: Which values for AA and BB would you like to keep (because ID == 1 has multiple)?

Comment: yep. really any!

Comment: the only thing is, If if for ID1 is saved the row 2, then I want AA and BB rows 2 saved too. I am not sure that makes sense

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the two new columns. The code now always takes the first row from the original data for each ID. You could make a different choice if you want.
If the answer is OK you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Dear @pieterbons, I am sorry but this doesn't solve it completely. It does in this case, but not in for example negative is in the first row. So I would be picking a value of AA and BB associated to a negative value and pairing it with a positive value. I have updated the post to make it a bit more clear. Hope it helps!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: solved with df <- df[order(df$ID, -xtfrm(df$antibodies)),]
#df <- df[order(-xtfrm(df$antibodies)),] #Alternative if ID order not important
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]. by GKi (below)

Comment: I also updated the anwer by first arranging the rows such that the first row is always a positive one if there is any.

Comment: It works! really appreciate it! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order` and `duplicated`.

```
df <- df[order(df$ID, -xtfrm(df$antibodies)),]
#df <- df[order(-xtfrm(df$antibodies)),] #Alternative if ID order not important
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
#  ID antibodies   AA   BB
#1  1   positive  123 3453
#5  2   negative 8679   78
#9  3   positive  567  786
```

or without `xtfrm` and no sorting with *ID*:

```
df <- df[order(df$antibodies),]
df[!duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Comment: thanks!! this works!!!

Comment: Could I ask what is -xtfrm for? thanks! @GKi

Comment: That's only needed that you can place an `-` before it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code you can explore in Base-R.

```
new_df <- data.frame(PatientID = unique(old_df$PatientID))
new_df$antibodies <- sapply(split(old_df$antibodies,old_df$PatientID), function(x) any(x=="positive"))
```

Thanks to [@pierterbons example data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891657/10442423) we get an output of

```
  PatientID antibodies
1         1       TRUE
2         2      FALSE
3         3       TRUE
```